# Is there a use for a void field?

Tags: c#, field, void

I made an typo in a file I was writing and discovered that there is no compiler error on declaring a void field type:

```
class MyClass
{
    object value;
    void otherValue; // I would have expected a compiler error
}
```

The fact that it is allowed implies to me that there is a use for such a field, but I do not know of one. Trying to set it *does* generate a compile error. So, is there a use for this, or is it some artifact of how the compiler works that has no function?

**Edit**
Something went wrong with visual studio that it was not compiling (and thus not giving me an error) Restarted it and it gave me the error. This is embarrassing.

Comment: in vs2010, i get a compiler error. "Field type cannot be 'void'".

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Except it is a compiler error.

Comment: I get a compile error: **Field cannot have void type**

Comment: Your code raises a `Field cannot have void type` error

Comment: If i am not wrong, a delegate of void type can be used

Comment: It works for me in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: I'm getting "Keyword 'void' cannot be used in this context", VS 2010

Comment: VS2010 give me a compile error saying that you cannot have a void field type.

Comment: @Fr33dan post your entire code.

Comment: That's not a _typo_, more like a Freudian slip.

Comment: Void can be used to declare pointers. but in your case, the declaration is not for a pointer, hence, I am stumped. Here is the link to pointers using void  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I smell a NARQ.

Comment: @GrantThomas the two frequently overlap. A lot of hot questions get closed - reopened - closed.

Comment: compile fails in VS2012 as well. there is something else in your env that makes it compile. Will be curious to know why it compiles.

Comment: **What** error do you get when you try to set it, and can you edit that code into your question?

Comment: i do think this a curious question worth investigating. reopen+1.

Comment: I'm quite sure you must be using `void*` in an [unsafe context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yah0tteb.aspx).

`void*` can be used to refer to [pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y31yhkeb.aspx) of an unknown type.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen _if_ @Fr33dan posts a full sample program. As it stands now, I suspect we are looking at two different things.

Comment: @Fr33dan: No problem about the mixup. +1 for humility!

Comment: For this to be an issue with unsafe code the class would have to be marked `unsafe` and the field would have to be declared as a pointer `void* otherValue`.  IMO, going from what the OP posted to that is an oustanding reach.

Comment: void is the new null

Answer (score 3):

### And i am 100% sure it is a compiler error

#### I have tested the code on Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010 & 2012 (confirmed by : [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd))

[image: Compiler error]

Error Message :

```
Error   1   Field cannot have void type C:\Users\Mr Master Minded\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  31  9   ConsoleApplication1
```